# How to manually install a tts voice?

Tags: windows-10, tts

Okay so i recently downloaded a text to speech pack but, The pack must be old because it doesn't come with an install just a zip file with all the .tts files and i have no idea how to manually install these, anyone have a clue on how to do this?